# Detect internet working or not in Cordova Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I want show message when internet not working in cordova Ionic Application, Can anybody done this in Ionic Cordova Application.

Comment: When you google for "cordova internet plugin" this is the first result: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md

Answer (score 6):

There is a [network-information plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md) to get network information from the device. Add the

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

include it and in app.js and register an offline event handler from within the `onDeviceReady`event handler,

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
},

onOffline: function () {
  //handle offline 
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, but if you want another, you can check to see if the internet exists when you launch your application: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/check-network-connection-with-ionicframework/

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple actually.
Add the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

You don't need to include anything in index.html. Just add $cordovaNetwork on the controller you are using. And, the following snippet will go well with it.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
 // Check for network connection
    if(window.Connection) {
    //you can log your connection as well, whether it is internet, wifi and so on.In this case you are checking for no connection
alert(navigator.connection.type);
      if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
        $ionicPopup.confirm({
          title: 'Network Problem',
          content: 'Sorry, Please Check Your Network Connection.'
        })
//or you can simply navigate it to a page with the no internet connection html.
      }
    }
})
```

//This is one of the way. The next way is having the following snippet in the controller you want to use. Don't forget to add the $cordovaNetwork, $ionicPlatform in this case.

```
var type = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();

   var isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();

    var isOffline = $cordovaNetwork.isOffline();

 $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
      var onlineState = networkState;
      alert(onlineState);
    })

 $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
      var offlineState = networkState;
       alert(offlineState);
    })

 document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online',function(event,networkState){
    $location.path('/japp/login');
  })

 $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline',function(event,networkState){
     $ionicPopup.confirm({
                        title: "Internet Disconnected",
                        content: "The internet is disconnected on your device."
                    }).then(function(){
                                    ionic.Platform.exitApp();
                    })
  })
```

If you are still having problem feel free to ask any small detail.

Answer (score 0):

here is some discussion on the ionic forum: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-check-network-coneection/15806/14

you can find a lot like this one. I would suggest to use ngCordova and do something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function() {});
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing plugin (cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information),   you can use following code inside app.js to show alert message

```
if(window.Connection) {
  console.log("checking connection");
    if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
      $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: "No Internet Connection",
        content: "Internet Connection is not available. In offline you can see previously fetched data.",
        okType:"balanced",
      })
      .then(function(result) {
          if(!result) {
            console.log('ok clicked');
          }
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi there is another issue here. Network information only tells you wether there is a connection. But that doesn't mean you have connection to a website and/or a running database. In most cases an app depends on the website and/or the database are available. So you have to check those too.